# What do you call someone who sends an email?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I searched for [sender](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/sender?s=t) synonyms but I'm not satisfied with the results

Comment: What's wrong with sender?

Comment: @Mynamite I'm programming an app with email functionnality. I have a "Recipient" class for the "to", but I think "Sender" sounds odd for "from". It's just notifications sent by my app. English is not my main language so I'm not sure what sound best.

Comment: Programming aps is not my thing, but I think 'sender' would be understood by most people. You send an email, therefore you are the sender.

Comment: @Mynamite then does Receiver sound better than recipient?

Comment: No, I'd stick with recipient. Phones have receivers (or used to in the old days) - it's more of an electrical word (radios etc), receiving signals.

Comment: You may use **Originator**, otherwise "Author", "Creator"  or "Writer".

Comment: We don't really encourage "guess which synonym I'll like best" questions such as this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Correspondent**, **from-name**, **message-author** (or shorter: **msg-author**), **first-author**, **communicator**.

The previously suggested words, "Author", "Creator" or "Writer", are all good choices.

You could use a word from another language, for example ***remitente***.

*Sender* is pretty good, by the way!

Comment: @loli - Now I'm curious -- which one did you choose?

Comment: I chose Author :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/e-mailer) (and others), *e-mailer* is an accepted word. Since the *-er* suffix generally means "one who (does something)," *e-mailer* can be understood to mean "one who e-mails." Surely there are better word choices, but this one most directly answers your question.

Comment: Out of context, I'd assume "e-mailer" was a Web 2.0 word for an email-based newsletter.